# Allow text wrap in li menu

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a menu that I have created with an unordered list. The menu cannot go over 900px wide, so I need my menu li text to sit on top of each other. Without shrinking the text size to 8px, is there a way to 'text-wrap' my menu item so it fits all nicely in the little box?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: KBDunkTank;
    src:url(KBDunkTank.ttf)
}

ul {
   /* margin: 20px 60px;*/
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 5px 0px 0 0;
    text-indent: 15px;
    position: relative;
 font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
   font-weight: 500;
 text-wrap: break-word;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
 text-decoration:none;

}

ul li:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 35px 0 35px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    z-index: 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul li:first-child:before {
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul li a:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
 top: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 35px 0 35px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #C34592;
    z-index: 10;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul li.active a {
    background: #FBE1EE;
    z-index: 100;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul li.active a:after {
    border-left-color: #FBE1EE;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #C34592;
 color: white;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #E899C9;
 
}

ul li a:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #E899C9;
 
}

#box{
 width: 900px;
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pick n Pack Game</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resume Rubric</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Career Guru</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Self Assessment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Image of what my menu looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reS3b.png)

[Link to my menu on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonekimber87/84cc7cus/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using 'word-wrap' and fiddled with the sizing of the borders and li for ages and finally got it...

```css
ul.progressBar {
   /* margin: 20px 60px;*/
}

ul.progressBar li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    /*text-indent: 20px;*/
    position: relative;
 font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
   font-weight: 500;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 
}

ul.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    z-index: 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul.progressBar li:first-child:before {
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul.progressBar li a:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
 top: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #C34592; /*Pink: C34592*/
    z-index: 10;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul.progressBar li.active a {
    background: #FBE1EE;
    z-index: 100;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul.progressBar li.active a:after {
    border-left-color: #FBE1EE;
}

ul.progressBar li a {
    display: block;
    background: #C34592; /*Pink: C34592*/
 color: black;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.progressBar li a:hover {
    background: #E899C9; /*Pink: E899C9*/
 
}

ul.progressBar li a:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #E899C9; /*Pink: E899C9*/
 
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressBar">
    <li><a href="#">Resume<br><br></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pick n Pack Game</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resume<br>Rubric</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Career<br>Guru</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Self<br>Assessment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submit<br><br></a></li>
</ul>
```